# Python Requests Get not Working (GCloud Debian 4.9.110)

Tags: python, python-requests, gcloud

I have a simple Get request I'd like to make using Python's Request library.

```
import requests
u_a = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"
url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/playergamelogs?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerID=202391&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2014-15&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&VsConference=&VsDivision='
response = requests.get(url, headers={"USER-AGENT":u_a})
```

The `requests.get` call hangs and I have to force the script to exit. However, I am able to make the same call on my local MacOS and Ubuntu machines. I can also copy/paste the url into my local computer's browsers and view the resulting JSON. Is the problem with the User Agent?

Edit (Added stacktrace):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prune_simulation.py", line 336, in <module>
    main()
  File "prune_simulation.py", line 44, in main
    response = requests.get(url, headers={"USER-AGENT":u_a})
  File "/home/nole/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nole/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nole/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/nole/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nole/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/nole/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/nole/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 377, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1121, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 438, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 394, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: what version of requests do you have installed in your environment?

Comment: @k.wahome 2.12.4

Comment: I managed to make the request with version '2.19.1'


Python 3.7.0 (default, Aug  4 2018, 02:33:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux

>>> import requests
>>> u_a = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"
>>> url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/playergamelogs?...'
>>> response = requests.get(url, headers={"USER-AGENT":u_a})
>>> response
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.__version__
'2.19.1'

Comment: Highly unlikely it's the user agent. Probably a good idea to upgrade to a newer version of requests as it could be a bug from before. Also add in a read `timeout` in the request so that it gets killed if the server unnecessarily takes too long (I'm not saying this is what is happening)
`requests.get(url, headers={"USER-AGENT":u_a}, timeout=10) `

Comment: Works with requests version 2.9.1 with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.

Comment: Hmm I updated requests to 2.19.1, but still getting same error. Using Python 2.7

Comment: @Nole It seems then it's an issue confined to your environment. Perhaps more details about your environment, how you are running the script. Is there any stack trace thrown once you kill the script?

Comment: @k.wahome Added stack trace

Comment: @Nole Looks like it's hanging in the socket module `self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)` which would most likely be related to a TCP connection failing over. It essentially looks like there is a networking related problem underlying the request going out to the server and a response being received probably a http proxy tunneling issue. What happens when you set a timeout say 5s?

Comment: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3353

Comment: @k.wahome Here is the error after adding timeout=5

requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='stats.nba.com', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)

Comment: @Nole I have tried to reproduce and the only time I hit the issue you are having is if I don't send the user agent. Or if I send an empty user agent like `requests.get(url, headers={"USER-AGENT":""})`
Try printing out the u_a just before calling requests.get to see it's value

Comment: @k.wahome Yeah I'm able to print out the u_a before `requests.get`. The u_a is still there.

Comment: @k.wahome Doesn't look like I'll solve the problem, but thank you for your help. I appreciate the effort.